# xgboost4j java library compiling failure

Tags: xgboost

Environment info

Operating System:Linux(CentOS6.5)

Compiler:gcc/g++

Package used (python/R/jvm/C++):jvm

xgboost version used:0.7

gcc-version: 7.1.0
cmake-version:3.10.0

Steps to reproduce

make -j4(Successfully)
2.mvn -DskipTests install(Failure in xgboost4j compiling)
What have you tried?

1.Set cmake
2.export CXX=clang-omp++

This is log:

> -- Found OpenMP_C: -fopenmp
>   -- Found OpenMP_CXX: -fopenmp
>   -- Found OpenMP_C: -fopenmp
>   -- Found OpenMP_CXX: -fopenmp
>   -- Configuring done
>   -- Generating done
>   -- Build files have been written to: /usr/local/xgboost/build [ 1%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rabit.dir/rabit/src/allreduce_base.cc.o
>   In file included from
>   /usr/local/xgboost/rabit/src/./../include/rabit/internal/../../dmlc/./logging.h:15,
>   from
>   /usr/local/xgboost/rabit/src/./../include/rabit/internal/../../dmlc/io.h:14,
>   from
>   /usr/local/xgboost/rabit/src/./../include/rabit/internal/../serializable.h:12,
>   from
>   /usr/local/xgboost/rabit/src/./../include/rabit/internal/engine.h:10,
>   from /usr/local/xgboost/rabit/src/./allreduce_base.h:19, from
>   /usr/local/xgboost/rabit/src/allreduce_base.cc:14:
>   /usr/local/xgboost/rabit/src/./../include/rabit/internal/../../dmlc/././base.h:105:
>   note: #pragma message: Will need g++-4.6 or higher to compile allthe
>   features in dmlc-core, compile without c++0x, some features may be
>   disabled In file included from
>   /usr/local/xgboost/rabit/src/./../include/rabit/internal/../../dmlc/io.h:14,
>   from
>   /usr/local/xgboost/rabit/src/./../include/rabit/internal/../serializable.h:12,
>   from
>   /usr/local/xgboost/rabit/src/./../include/rabit/internal/engine.h:10,
>   from /usr/local/xgboost/rabit/src/./allreduce_base.h:19, from
>   /usr/local/xgboost/rabit/src/allreduce_base.cc:14:
>   /usr/local/xgboost/rabit/src/./../include/rabit/internal/../../dmlc/./logging.h:
>   In constructor ?.mlc::LogCheckError::LogCheckError()?.
>   /usr/local/xgboost/rabit/src/./../include/rabit/internal/../../dmlc/./logging.h:66:
>   error: ?.ullptr?.was not declared in this scope
>   /usr/local/xgboost/rabit/src/./../include/rabit/internal/../../dmlc/./logging.h:
>   In destructor ?.mlc::LogCheckError::~LogCheckError()?.
>   /usr/local/xgboost/rabit/src/./../include/rabit/internal/../../dmlc/./logging.h:68:
>   error: ?.ullptr?.was not declared in this scope
>   /usr/local/xgboost/rabit/src/./../include/rabit/internal/../../dmlc/./logging.h:
>   In member function ?.mlc::LogCheckError::operator bool()?.
>   /usr/local/xgboost/rabit/src/./../include/rabit/internal/../../dmlc/./logging.h:69:
>   error: ?.ullptr?.was not declared in this scope In file included from
>   /usr/local/xgboost/rabit/src/./../include/rabit/internal/../../dmlc/io.h:14,
>   from
>   /usr/local/xgboost/rabit/src/./../include/rabit/internal/../serializable.h:12,
>   from
>   /usr/local/xgboost/rabit/src/./../include/rabit/internal/engine.h:10,
>   from /usr/local/xgboost/rabit/src/./allreduce_base.h:19, from
>   /usr/local/xgboost/rabit/src/allreduce_base.cc:14:
>   /usr/local/xgboost/rabit/src/./../include/rabit/internal/../../dmlc/./logging.h:
>   In destructor ?.mlc::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()?.
>   /usr/local/xgboost/rabit/src/./../include/rabit/internal/../../dmlc/./logging.h:289:
>   error: ?.ullptr?.was not declared in this scope gmake[2]: ***
>   [CMakeFiles/rabit.dir/rabit/src/allreduce_base.cc.o] Error 1 building
>   Java wrapper cd .. mkdir -p build cd build cmake ..
>   -DUSE_OPENMP:BOOL=ON -DUSE_HDFS:BOOL=OFF -DUSE_AZURE:BOOL=OFF -DUSE_S3:BOOL=OFF -DPLUGIN_UPDATER_GPU:BOOL=OFF -DJVM_BINDINGS:BOOL=ON cmake --build . --config Release gmake[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uioNf.png): ***
>   [CMakeFiles/rabit.dir/all] Error 2 gmake: *** [all] Error 2 Traceback
>   (most recent call last): File "create_jni.py", line 89, in  run("cmake
>   --build . --config Release") File "create_jni.py", line 51, in run subprocess.check_call(command, shell=True, **kwargs) File
>   "/root/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line
>   291, in check_call raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
>   subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'cmake --build . --config
>   Release' returned non-zero exit status 2. [ERROR] Command execution
>   failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with
>   an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) at
>   org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:804)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:751)
>   at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:313) at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307) at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193) at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106) at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863) at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288) at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>   [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Reactor Summary: [INFO] [INFO] xgboost-jvm
>   ........................................ SUCCESS [ 7.834 s] [INFO]
>   xgboost4j .......................................... FAILURE [ 5.489
>   s] [INFO] xgboost4j-spark .................................... SKIPPED
>   [INFO] xgboost4j-flink .................................... SKIPPED
>   [INFO] xgboost4j-example .................................. SKIPPED
>   [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 13.619 s [INFO] Finished at:
>   2017-12-14T03:13:07+08:00 [INFO] Final Memory: 23M/55M [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (native) on project
>   xgboost4j: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1
>   (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1] [ERROR] [ERROR] To see the full stack
>   trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run
>   Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions,
>   please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
>   [ERROR] [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the
>   build with the command [ERROR] mvn -rf :xgboost4j
>   [Failure log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uioNf.png)
>   Which step can I try to resolve the problem, mostly is to enable c++11 feature in cmake, it is very important.